# Copy files matching a pattern in makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to copy a file which matches the pattern

> *_$YEAR_$MONTH_$DAY_*_gitlab_backup.tar

and present inside a folder **/var/opt/gitlab/backups/**

My make target is as follows.

```
backup.gitlab-ee:
    docker cp gitlab-gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/*_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}_*_gitlab_backup.tar /home/centos/gitlab-backups/${today}-GitLabBackup/
```

I also tried this

```
backup.gitlab-ee:
        docker cp gitlab-gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/$(wildcard *_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}_*_gitlab_backup.tar ) /home/centos/gitlab-backups/${today}-GitLabBackup/
```

but this copies whole **backup** folder and not the file with pattern.

Comment: can you get the docker command to work on the command line? (In general, you can't do something with Make unless you know how to do it *without* Make.)

Comment: @Beta I have tested these commands. they do work. I still have the question of matching filename by pattern.

Comment: What does make print for the command line when you run the first example?  Does it look right to you?